# PrimeFaces 6.0 + Bootstrap Theme + FontAwesome Combination: Icon not shown correctly

Tags: primefaces, font-awesome

I'm using Primefaces in combination with the bootstrap theme and have the problem that icons aren't scaled according to the button size / button text.

[image]

I'm embedding the icons in the components this way:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Update" icon="fa fa-fw fa-refresh" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try an other icon to see if the problem is from the icon ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight yeah I did. By the way if the type="button" attribute is set I the actionListener isn't called. Therefore I removed this attribute afterwards.